# Applescript and Cocoa modal session

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog, applescript, nswindow

OSX 10.12
This is the scenario: there is an app that at launch shows modal sheet with progress bar. Then, after some period of time the sheet closes and the app is ready for work.
The code responsible for this is next:

```
-(void) open{
    [self showWindow:nil];

    [self.sheet setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO];
    [self.mainWindow beginSheet: self.sheet
      completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
          [NSApp stopModalWithCode: returnCode];
    }];

    [self.progbar setIndeterminate:YES];
    [self.progbar startAnimation:nil];
}
```

and

```
-(void) close{
    if(self.sheet){
        [self.progbar stopAnimation:nil];
        [self.mainWindow endSheet:self.sheet];
    }
}
```

The modal sheet introduces the Cancel button which having been pressed closes the sheet.
Also I have the Applescript program that launches this app:

```
tell application "xyz.app"
    activate
    do something
end tell
```

This script launches the app and modal sheet appears and disappears - as required.
**However**, this script

```
tell application "xyz.app"
    do something
end tell
```

launches the app, sheet appears and **does not disappear**. Pressing on button Cancel does not help - the modal sheet stays **stuck**.
Can anyone explain this?

**Update:** method *close* always executed

Comment: Is the `close` method executed?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with a wrinkle - I wanted a modal alert box fade-out with a default return value. This does not get stuck, it does a modal block until either the fade-out completes or the user selects one of the buttons.

```
    - (BOOL) warningAlert:(NSString* )messageText informText:(NSString*)informText {
  // Displays a fading, then self-dismissing view within the top level window

  __block NSInteger alertReturn = 0; // __block, so it can be accessed by the completion blocks

  // Define the alert
  NSAlert* __block generalAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
  [generalAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Continue?"];
  [generalAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
  [generalAlert setMessageText:messageText];
  [generalAlert setInformativeText:informText];
  [generalAlert setAlertStyle:NSAlertStyleWarning];

  // Animate the fading box, with the passed completion criteria alertReturn = NSModalResponseStop
  [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
  // Animate alpha fade
  [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:5.0];
  [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
    // Dismiss the alert
    NSWindow *window = [NSApp mainWindow];
    [[window attachedSheet] close];
    NSLog(@"Closed the Sheet");
    alertReturn = NSModalResponseStop;
  }];
  [[generalAlert.window animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
  [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

  // Begin the alert.
  // For the completion criteria, speed up the animation to it's conclusion, but not before we return to the calling method
  [generalAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.mySwiftCentral.sxWindowController.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.01];
    [[generalAlert.window animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
    alertReturn = result;
    NSLog(@"Success, alertReturn = %ld",(long)alertReturn);
  }];

  // Create a NSModalSession using the global Application Instance variable NSApp
  NSModalSession session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:
                            self.mywindow];
  alertReturn = NSModalResponseContinue;

  // Loop here until the user responds or the animation completes, either of which will modify alertReturn and break out of the loop
  // Without the NSModalSession, this loop would block user button actions or animation timeout.
  for (;;) {
    [NSApp runModalSession:session];
    if (alertReturn != NSModalResponseContinue)
      break;
    // Break on timeout here
  }
  [NSApp endModalSession:session];

  NSLog(@"Alert Return = %ld",(long)alertReturn);
  if (alertReturn == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn ||
      alertReturn == NSModalResponseStop) {
    return YES;
  }
  else return NO;

}
```